# Ajax not recognizing custom response header from page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, header, progress-bar

I'm trying to make a progress bar so I used APC apache extension to make this: http://pastebin.com/TBui6ckT

I used: `header("Percent:".$percent);` to give the percent as a header when you call the site. So I went back to the index page a used ajax to call that progress page and check the header that I made called "Percent" and change something on the main page to that number. Heres the script for that: http://pastebin.com/NkQv2Uq0 the var test; is just temporary, I will change it to:

```
if(xmlhttp.getResponseHeader("Percent")<=100) ...
```

I'm thinking it's the the header just returning "Header: 'percent'%" as a string ... but I'm not sure. Also I know for a fact it's the header because if I put in: `document.getElementById('progress_number').innerHTML=xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders();` It returns every header including the Percent. But oddly it does not update it's self. You would think that it would loop with: `setTimeout(onSubmit(upload_id), 999);` but it does not.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm waiting for the question (mark)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second pastebin you have a bug

```
if(test=1)
```

it should be

```
if(test==1)
```

The second bug you have is your setTimeout is wrong

```
setTimeout(onSubmit(upload_id), 999);
```

should be

```
setTimeout(function(){ onSubmit(upload_id); }, 999);
```

Thirdly

```
if(xmlhttp.getResponseHeader("Percent")<=100)
```

`getResponseHeader` returns a string so you are comparing a string to a number. You would need to use `parseInt()`

```
if( parseInt( xmlhttp.getResponseHeader("Percent"), 10) <= 100 )
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I tried to make a responce on this question about the setTimeout() thing but you beat me too it. Thank you very much! I'll try to +rep you but I'm a fresh account I don't know if I can yet. Either way thank you very much!